# how to compare two files and display in table format

Tags: linux, shell-script, file-comparison

I need to compare two files and display the difference in table format using shell script.
for example.

file1.txt

```
ap-2.21.3.rpm
bp-3.42.4.rpm
cp-devel-3.23.2.rpm
ep-devel- 2.23.2-23.rpm
```

file2.txt

```
ap-2.21.3.rpm
bp-3.43.4.rpm
cp-devel-4.33.2.rpm
dp-4.52.4.rpm
```

output will be in:

```
Name                           |        file1              | file2
-------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
bp                             |         3.42.4            | 3.43.4
cp-devel                       |         3.23.2            | 4.33.2
dp                             |                           | 4.52.4
ep-devel                       |         2.23.2-23         |
```

Comment: Is the filextension always `.rpm`. Consist the version number always of three blocks of numbers?

Comment: yes the file extension is always .rpm . but the version number blocks will differ sometimes it will be 5 to 6 blocks of numbers.

Comment: This is not comparing files, which could be achieved by `diff`. This is more like comparing data in database from two different tables. Certainly doable in shell, but maybe that's not the right way to do it?

Comment: i tried diff but i am not getting output what i want. is any other way to do this?

Comment: Do the package names contain exactly one hyphen, or can you have `ap-dev.2.35.foo-bar.3.rpm` ?

Comment: some of them only one, some of them more than two.

Comment: for example like this python-2.6.9-0.33.1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: In your python example, what do you want for Name? python or python-2.6.9 ? Do you want the architecture x86_64 to be kept as part of the version string, or omitted?

Comment: i need only python. and can omit architecture

Comment: Just one more question: If you have a package named `python-devel-2.6.9-0.33.1.x86_64.rpm`,  is the Name python or python-devel?

Comment: yes for that i need python-devel as package name

Answer (score 1):

1. `cat file1| awk -F "-" '{print $2}'| sed "s/\.[a-z].*//g">file_1_final.txt`
2. `cat file2| awk -F "-" '{print $2}'| sed "s/\.[a-z].*//g">file_2_final.txt`
3. `paste file_1_final.txt file_2_final.txt  | sed '1i file1     file2' >combined_file1_file2`
4. `awk -F "-"  'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $1}' file1 file2>>common_difference_file_1_2`
5. `awk -F "-"  'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}' file1 file2>>common_difference_file_1_2`
6. `sed -i '1i name' common_difference_file_1_2`
7. `paste common_difference_file_1_2 combined_file1_file2`

Output:

```
name    file1     file2
ap  2.21.3  2.35.3
bp  3.42.4  3.43.4
cp  3.23.2  4.33.2
dp      4.52.4
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen Kumar BS, Thanks for the solution. its working now with this example. what if i have the name and version like this ap-devel-2.21.3-4.4.65.rpm. here name is ap-devel and version is 2.21.3-4.4.65.

Comment: I think it works fine even in this case too test  and let me know for any doubts

Comment: I tried In that case and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments one can describe the filenames like this:

- the program version consists of numbers, dots and hyphens and is preceded by a hyphen
- the program names are all characters before that hyphen
- the version number is delimited to the next block by a dot followed by a letter

With these information one can use `sed` to transform the names in a table per file containing only the program name and the version number:

```
$ sed -n 's|^\(.\+\)-\([0-9.-]\+\)\..*|\1 \2|p' file1.txt 
$ sed -n 's|^\(.\+\)-\([0-9.-]\+\)\..*|\1 \2|p' file2.txt
```

One can then use `awk` to collect the program names in the two files, store which version of each program is in each file and print a summary table:

```
$ awk -v FS=" " -v OFS="\t" ' \
    { program[$1]++; } \
    NR==FNR { f1[$1] = $2; next; } \
    { f2[$1] = $2; } \
    END { for(i in program) print i, f1[i], f2[i]; }' \
   <(sed -n 's|^\(.\+\)-\([0-9.-]\+\)\..*|\1 \2|p' file1.txt) \
   <(sed -n 's|^\(.\+\)-\([0-9.-]\+\)\..*|\1 \2|p' file2.txt)
```